# Regex to detect this pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have the following format and I want to check it with regular expression:

```
2016-05-24T22:00:00
```

If I want to do it with simple java manipulation it will be very easy. But I think doing it in regx is much more efficient. Can anyone help me how to do that with regx?(I am totally new to regex )

Comment: Try at least a bit... Practice [here](https://regex101.com/r/eF0iQ8/1)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to spot dates in longer texts? Or you have the dates already and you want to parse them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex does the work:

```
\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}T\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ7rD0/1). Description:

```
\d{4} match a digit [0-9]

    Quantifier: {4} Exactly 4 times

(?:-\d{2}){2} Non-capturing group

    Quantifier: {2} Exactly 2 times
    - matches the character - literally
    \d{2} match a digit [0-9]
        Quantifier: {2} Exactly 2 times

T matches the character T literally (case sensitive)
\d{2} match a digit [0-9]

    Quantifier: {2} Exactly 2 times

(?::\d{2}){2} Non-capturing group

    Quantifier: {2} Exactly 2 times
    : matches the character : literally
    \d{2} match a digit [0-9]
        Quantifier: {2} Exactly 2 times
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you aren't familiar with regular expressions, let's look at what you need to match :

- **A Date** (that is explicitly in the format `YYYY-MM-dd`)
- **A Time** (that starts with `T` and is in the format `hh:mm:ss`).

So you really only need to match a few specific characters (`-`,`T` and `:`) and everything else is just a digit `\d`. So a very basic example that would match any numbers that meet this pattern might look like :

```
\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
```

**What is this doing?**

```
\d{4}       # Matches four consecutive digits (year)
\-          # Matches an explicit dash (separating years and months)
\d{2}       # Matches two consecutive digits (months)
\-          # Matches another dash (months and days)
\d{2}       # Matches two more digits (days)
T           # Matches a T (indicating the start of your time)
\d{2}       # Matches two digits (hours)
:           # Matches a colon (between hours and minutes)
\d{2}       # Matches two more digits (minutes)
:           # Matches another colon (minutes and seconds)
\d{2}       # Finally, matches two digits for seconds
```

This is obviously a very basic approach and it could certainly be shorted as seen by [Thomas' response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37463031/557445). I just wanted to help give you an idea of how you might go about constructing an expression to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot your post was very helpful and gave me clue from where to start

Answer (score 2):

beware of previous simple answer cause they accept even things like 2016-75-92T40:25:82 with no kind of constraint and you are gonna need to enforce them separately

just to give you an example this matches any 4 digit years and from 01 to 12 month

```
\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])
```

but limiting days is gonna be a pain

Comment: The question is not about having a *valid date* but a regex that match this pattern ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `SimpleDateFormat` instead. It has everything you need, like checks if hours fit into the number range. You can skip these checks, otherwise it's a horror task for a regex.

Answer (score 1):

First understand how regex works so Formatting becomes really simple, here is the answer use

`\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}`

> Here is the Explanation:

`\` is used as for escape sequence in many programming languages and so in java.
d represents the decimal Integer

do some reading on Formatting Numeric Print Output it will help you in understanding pattern specification.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html